# How to force a user to select an option, using frames, excel userform

Tags: excel, userform, vba

[image]I have 4 frames on my userform.

Frames 1, 2, and 4 have two option buttons. 
Frame 3 has 5 options buttons.

What I want to do, is that when the command button is selected, that if an option button in a frame has not been selected, a message will appear.

**I would like to have a custom message for each frame.**

I have made a start, but really struggling to get to grips with the different frames... can someone point me in the right direction? (Still very beginner and trying to learn, so if all replies could be dumbed-down, that would be great!! :D )

(I have pulled this code from an example, so it might not be the best approach to my problem...)

```
Dim ThisControl As Control

For Each ThisControl In UserForm2.Frame1.Controls

If TypeName(ThisControl) = "OptionButton" And _
ThisControl.Value = True Then
Unload Me
End If

Next ThisControl
MsgBox "Please Select an Option", vbCritical, "Select Opton"
```

Comment: Are you trying to have nested options? Like if `MasterOption1` is selected, then check at least one of the `SlaveOptions` are selected. The master options are then split in to frames? It might be an idea to screenshot your form

Comment: Hi SilverShotBee -- thanks for your comment. I have taken your advice and included a picture to the OP. You can see the four frames at the top -- existing customer/age/gender/product enquiry. I appreciate your help and thoughts about how to get this to work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
If Me.[ControlName].Value = False And Me.[ControlName].Value = False Then
    MsgBox "[Message]", vbExclamation, "[Message Box Name]"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Do the same for each frame, replacing [ControlName] with the control's name and replacing [Message] and [Message Box Name] with the custom message you want.
For frame 3, you will need to include an additional 3 'And' statements.

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you! I now have a related-question, I want your code to work with my multipage... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699926/multipage-cant-validate-option-buttons-inside-a-frame-excel-vba

Answer (score 3):

Probably not the most eligant solution, but it works fine. Cycles through each frame (you will need to update frame names to match yours [Name, not caption!]), then makes sure at least one option is set, else shows a message. Adapt as needed

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()       


For Each ctrl In Frame1.Controls

   If TypeOf ctrl Is msforms.OptionButton Then

       If ctrl.Value = True Then
             F1D = True
             Exit For
             End If
       End If
   Next ctrl

If F1D = False Then
MsgBox "No Option Selected In Frame 1"
End If

For Each ctrl In Frame2.Controls

   If TypeOf ctrl Is msforms.OptionButton Then

       If ctrl.Value = True Then
             F2D = True
             Exit For
             End If
       End If
   Next ctrl

If F2D = False Then
MsgBox "No Option Selected In Frame 2"
End If

For Each ctrl In Frame3.Controls

   If TypeOf ctrl Is msforms.OptionButton Then

       If ctrl.Value = True Then
             F3D = True
             Exit For
             End If
       End If
   Next ctrl

If F3D = False Then
MsgBox "No Option Selected In Frame 3"
End If

For Each ctrl In Frame4.Controls

   If TypeOf ctrl Is msforms.OptionButton Then

       If ctrl.Value = True Then
             F4D = True
             Exit For
             End If
       End If
   Next ctrl

If F4D = False Then
MsgBox "No Option Selected In Frame 4"
End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks SilverShotBee. I used the code up but +voted your solution. I now have another related problem.. maybe you can help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699926/multipage-cant-validate-option-buttons-inside-a-frame-excel-vba