# multipage -- can't validate option buttons inside a frame - excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a two-page userform, all currently working correctly (almost).

When my users hit the command button on the first page, I want them to be sent to the second page, only if a specific option button is selected:

```
 If ProductEnquiryYes.Value = True Then
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
closeForm = False
Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = 1
End If
```

So, if the product enquiry option is checked - they should go to the next page. 
If the product enquiry option is not checked, users should end the form. (The tab headings will be hidden)

However, I now want to validate the options in a frame on the first page, so that an option inside each frame must be selected. I'm almost there, but if the users haven't selected an option the warning appears but the users go to the next page. (i.e. the users are getting the warning too late)

[image]

**What I need my code to do is check that the option buttons have been validated BEFORE it decides whether or not to send my users to the next page or close the form.**

Can someone help? Hopefully my question is clear.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

Dim closeForm As Boolean

' we assume we want the form closed unless there is a reason to go to the Extra tab
closeForm = True


'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A")) + 1

'Did customer ask about product?

If ProductEnquiryYes.Value = True Then
Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
closeForm = False
Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = 1
End If

If ProductEnquiryNo.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 21).Value = 1
End If

'=========================================================
'Services
'=========================================================

'Balance Enquiry
If BalanceEnquiry.Value = True Then
    Cells(emptyRow, 23).Value = 1
End If


'==========================================================
'Ensure Options in the frames are selected

If Me.YesCustomerOption.Value = False And Me.NoCustomerOption.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "Please ensure you have selected an option for 'Is the customer an existing ASB customer?'", vbExclamation, "Failed to select an option"
    Exit Sub
End If

'==========================================================

'Close Userform
If closeForm Then Unload Me


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code that switches to the second page is before your check to make sure the form is validated.  If you want to make sure that these two conditions are met before doing anything else, you should move this section of code to be earlier:

```
If Me.YesCustomerOption.Value = False And Me.NoCustomerOption.Value = False Then
    MsgBox "Please ensure you have selected an option for 'Is the customer an existing ASB customer?'", vbExclamation, "Failed to select an option"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

If those are the two primary checks, move that whole if block to be before this section:

```
If ProductEnquiryYes.Value = True Then
    Me.MultiPage1.Value = 1
    closeForm = False
    Cells(emptyRow, 20).Value = 1
End If
```

Comment: Hi Sous - top marks again. Thanks. I tried moving it up, but placed it just underneath where you suggested. Oops! At least I was half on the right track :P

Comment: I have two very final questions about my form. Do you think we could chat again? :)